# How to check whether Google User's image is default or uploaded?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

How do I check whether user's profile picture is default or uploaded in Google?

**Note**: When you get user details from APIs.

[image: Google User's Default Image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of default profile pictures have the following URL:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg
```

You can just compare string equality of profile picture with the given one.

Comment: this string seem to have changed but it's still true that default images contain `AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA` and ends in `photo.jpg`.

Comment: This has changed and default images don't contain such URL patterns anymore.
To know whether the user profile picture is real or default, we can leverage the ``people`` API as mentioned by @incaren in the below answer.

Answer (score 7):

[people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) includes a `isDefault` value in the image object. E.g. if you try it for `+Google` you will get;

```
"image": {
    "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAACyas/yR1_yhwBcBA/photo.jpg?sz=50",
    "isDefault": false
}
```

Comment: What is it in case it's not available? False by default, or true by default?

Comment: @androiddeveloper It's `false` by default: if `default` is omitted from the API, it means that it's user-set

Answer (score 7):

people.get no longer has isDefault as a property.
https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource

Comment: I tried this a minute ago. It gave isDefault": false. Please can you clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

Updating this answer for 2020: it's now possible to get the user's profile picture by sending a request to the `people.get` API with `photos` as the `personFields` to request.

You'll get back an array of images, and whenever `default: true` is present, it means it's a default (not user-set) image:

Example (if you're using this with OAuth):

GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me

**Sample response (with profile picture)**

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/117055959617985617271",
  "etag": "%EgQBAzcuGgQBAgUHIgxHamp6MG9wZ3hOcz0=",
  "photos": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "117055959617985617271"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gg_-udXd3O6K1URTBTEK2rLa2DOh6G2dgmOHcOBOtE=s100"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "2"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/default-user=s100",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample response (default only)**

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/113009277022343767972",
  "etag": "%EgQBAzcuGgQBAgUHIgxxdHVTY3IxZVJIUT0=",
  "photos": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "113009277022343767972"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6NS3awoYRXw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucnTo-mElIpcAEazDV9DAs1VyYDEIw/s100/photo.jpg",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ruby with devise and omniauth-google-oauth2

in your devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2 (Other options....), skip_image_info: false
```

then in your user.rb / other place:

```
def self.parse_auth_image(auth)
  if auth.provider == "google_oauth2"
    return nil if auth.dig("extra", "raw_info", "image", "isDefault")
  end
  auth.info.image
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this in FULL DETAIL:

```
require 'open-uri'
```

Default image:

```
default = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-
XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg"
```

Image to check:

```
image_to_check = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-
uh4wK1JDtCI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/huieBSbV4zg/s64-
c/100695019739939096169.jpg"
```

Comparison check

```
blob_for_default_image = open(default).read

blob_for_image_to_check = open(image_to_check).read
```

Then you compare the 2 image blobs:

```
blob_for_default_image == blob_for_image_to_check
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using PHP, It's fairly simple, just use this code

```
$profile_img_end = explode("/", $userData['picture']); // Exploding the URL and Dividing it into several terms

if (end($profile_img_end) === "photo.jpg") { // Now Simply Check if last part of array is equal to "photo.jpg" which is common in all default images
    $profile_img = null; // If it's default then set it equal to null
} else {
    $profile_img = $userData['picture']; // Else get the Link of the Image
}
```

**Alternative in JavaScript**

```
var url = ""; // Image URL

var img_split = url.split("/"); // Split it Again from / (forward slash)

if (img_split[img_split.length - 1] === 'photo.jpg') { // Check if last array is equal to photo.jpg (By Default Image)
   var image = null;
} else {
   var image = url;
}
```

**HOPE IT HELPS!**

Comment: This answer can not be true...not for 2021(?)
At least in 2023 the image url looks like that: