# GoogleSignIn, Unable to detect if user has set any profile image or not

Tags: ios, google-signin, google-profiles-api

I am supposed to display an default image set by my app, in case no profile image has been set by the user. For which i need to detect whether user has set any profile image or not in his google account.

Now, upon accessing profile image for a user who has not set any image yet, api is returning default profile image set by google. Also, **hasImage** property resulted to be of no use, as it always returns true, even for this case.

[image]

Following is the API, which i used to access the profileImage
GoogleSignIn (3.0.0)

```
GIDProfileData->hasImage : "Whether or not the user has profile image"
GIDProfileData->imageURLWithDimension : "Gets the user's profile image URL for the given dimension in pixels for each side of the square"
```

[link to Documentation page](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_profile_data)

Here's the snippet for accessing the profile image :

```
if([GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.profile.hasImage) {

        NSUInteger imgSize = usrImgV.frame.size.height * 2;
        NSURL *imgUrl = [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.profile imageURLWithDimension:imgSize];
        [usrImgV setImageWithURL:imgUrl placeholderImage:placeholderImg];

    }
```

Last resort for this seems to compare the image, that will also break in case default image changes.

Comment: Gmail has this default image if user has not set his profile picture. So, "hasImage" attribute will always return true.

Comment: @AneeqAnwar, then what is the point of having this property if it is supposed return a constant value. Also, then there is no way to detect if user has chosen a profile image or not.

Comment: For google+ the image url has a property isDefault, if set to false..then you  will be getting current profile picture of user. Maybe you should try fetching image url for google sign in also.

Comment: I got ur answer. Create a NSData for the default image returned by google and compare it with the profile picture. If it is true then return default image, if false , you will have your current profile picture.

Comment: @AkashKR, what you are suggesting is sort of image comparison. I want to stick to that as last option, as it has a dependency on the fact that default image is going to remain same. "isDefault" would had been best choice, but i don't thing they are serving it any more in their google API.

Comment: @Amit, so i guess no bounty then

Comment: @AkashKR, i am hoping there should some answer as it seems to be very common use case scenario.

Comment: @Amit, ok look for your desired answer. But you've asked for the answer irrespective of common use case scenario. So, if you fail bounty should be mine.

Comment: @Amit, here is a same questions as like your, Here is the link- 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649696/how-to-check-whether-google-users-image-is-default-or-uploaded

Visit this link may be it should be helpful to you.

Comment: @JigarTarsariya, that is valid for google plus api. I don't think that it applies also in case of google API.

Comment: I also want to distinguish between the default image and profile pic set by user....Did you find any answer for this. I cannot use google plus login. I want to implement this feature using Google login only...Kindly guide me ...

Comment: Having the same issue!

Comment: @Amit have you ever found answer for same?