# Don't get default picture google plus api

Tags: google-plus, google-signin

Is there a way to not get the default picture URL of google plus api

When I am doing:

```
GET /plus/v1/people/109991090897698795916?fields=image&amp;key=<MY_KEY> HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f1c6333b-29d6-ae04-332c-9dd629ecaa54
```

If user did not set a profile picture it returns me the default profile picture.
However I would like to not have this default profile picture. I have my own in case the picture is not defined

Do you have an idea?

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether Google User's image is default or uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649696/how-to-check-whether-google-users-image-is-default-or-uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how default google picture looks like, I suggest that you add your own logic after the API call by removing it and replace it by your own.