# How to filter user uploaded profile photo from google default profile photo

Tags: android, google-people-api

I am using **Google People API v1** to fetch user's photos. I want to use photos uploaded by the user to suggest profile pictures for my application. Is there any way to filter

[image]

from

[image: google provided default profile picture?]

The **Google+** api gives '**isDefault**' flag, and it is set to '**false**' for profile photos uploaded by the user
([How to check whether Google User's image is default or uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27649696/8148842)) but I am not able to find any similar structure in the People API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new `default` field has been recently added to the [Photo message](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Photo) in People API.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.