# Is there a way (via the API) to determine whether or not a user's Google profile image is Google's default profile image?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I used to be able to use the [Google+ API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649696/how-to-check-whether-google-users-image-is-default-or-uploaded) for this, but [that API is being shutdown](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown).

I'm wondering if there exists a way to **both**

1. Get the URL for a user's profile image
2. Know whether or not the image is Google's default image, or an image set by the user

I've found other Google APIs that provide an image URL, such as [oauth2.userinfo.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get), but I have been unable to find an API provides something like Google+'s `isDefault` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/). The API has a [`people.get`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) method which returns an instance of [`Person`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person):

```
{
  "resourceName": string,
  "etag": string,
  "metadata": {
    object(PersonMetadata)
  },
  ...
  "photos": [
    {
      object(Photo)
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

The `photos` field returns the person's read-only photos.

JSON representation:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    object(FieldMetadata)
  },
  "url": string,
  "default": boolean
}
```

where,

> - **metadata** - object([FieldMetadata](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.FieldMetadata))
>
>   - Metadata about the photo.
> - **url** - string
>
>   - The URL of the photo. You can change the desired size by appending a query parameter `sz=size` at the end of the url. Example:
>       `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T_wVWLlmg7w/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABa8/00gzXvDBYqw/s100/photo.jpg?sz=50`
> - **default** - boolean
>
>   - True if the photo is a default photo; false if the photo is a user-provided photo.