# How to tell between actual picture vs. default auto-generated image in Google OAuth?

Tags: google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

I'm retrieving user data from Google using the Passport Google Strategy ([OAuth 2.0](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/)). This works fine except when the logged-in user does not have an explicitly set profile picture. In such cases, Google returns a default image with the user's first-name initial:

[image]

I want to be able to tell if the image returned by the API is a real image or something like this. How do I accomplish this? There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649696/how-to-check-whether-google-users-image-is-default-or-uploaded) but the answer is outdated since Google no longer seems to offer an `isDefault` flag. Nor does it have a consistent URI for the default *silhouette* because the auto-generated image is different for different users depending on their initials. Is there any alternative flag offered by Google OAuth 2.0 that tells me if the image is an auto-generated one?

Comment: try checking out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62437962/14068351

Comment: I tried to execute the example given here: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22photos%22%7D 



and it did not respond with any value of "DEFAULT" True/false  (so I can not tell if this is a default image or an uploade done)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I've concluded, since Google+ will be discontinued and people.googleapis has been changed, as of 2023. I haven't found a way to know if the image you receive from Google is default or not.